# Why can't I make an object = bool in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, boolean

I have a program that I am trying to extend the object class to allow for a method that refers to all members of an Array.

Code of ExtendedArray class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleMaze
{
    class ExtendedArray : Object
    {
        private object[] referredTo;

        public ExtendedArray()
        {
            referredTo = null;
        }//empty constructor

        public ExtendedArray(Object[] obj)
        {
            referredTo = obj;
        }//full constructor

        public void referToAll(object changeTo)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < referredTo.Length; x++)
            {
                referredTo[x] = changeTo;
            }

        }//referToAll(bool)

    }//ExtendedArray <== class
}
```

I intend on using this class and adding things to it in the future so its very generic. Though when I try to use the constructor it errors out with cannot implicitly convert type bool[] to type object[].

```
Boolean[] dirBoolArray = { curLeft, curUp, curRight, curDown };
ExtendedArray dirBool = new ExtendedArray(dirBoolArray);
```

Comment: You can convert a nullable `bool?` to an object.

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to accomplish here. What's the intended usage of your extended array? How is it different from `List<T>`?

Comment: google Boxing boolean c#

Comment: Explanations aside, you almost certainly need to use generics here to solve the problem so that you can accept an array of `T`, rather than an array of objects.

Comment: BTW there is not need to explicitly inherit from `Object`. All classes inherit from it anyway.

Comment: @ja72 I figured as much but was unsure if it would make a difference. I thought it might make it able to accept a bool rather than just another of its own type.

Comment: +1 because you learned something now from posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you do this:

```
class ExtendedArray<T> 
{
    private T[] referredTo;

    public ExtendedArray()
    {
        referredTo=null;
    }//empty constructor

    public ExtendedArray(T[] obj)
    {
        referredTo=obj;
    }//full constructor

    public void referToAll(T changeTo)
    {
        for(int x=0; x<referredTo.Length; x++)
        {
            referredTo[x]=changeTo;
        }

    }//referToAll(bool)

}//ExtendedArray <== class

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExtendedArray<bool> array=new ExtendedArray<bool>(new bool[10]);
        array.referToAll(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The whole point of his type seems to be intentionally removing type safety, unless that was just an unintended side effect.  This here wouldn't have any advantage to just using a regular array.

Comment: I think you are just speculating. Let us see what the OP says.

Comment: @Servy I am trying to make it accept any kind of array thrown at it.

Note: I am a relatively new C# programmer though I have experience with Basic and Java. I also don't know what `T[]` means nor do I know what the `<bool>` syntax means.

Comment: Nevermind I went and looked up <T>. It all makes sense now, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to what you said in your title, you can assign `bool` to an `object` variable. The following code compiles fine:

```
bool b = true;
object o = b;
```

What the second line actually does is that it [boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) the `bool` value, which converts it from a value type to reference type.

What this means is that `b` is a single byte that directly contains the *value* `true`. On the other hand, `o` is a *reference* (4 or 8 bytes) that points to an object that contains a byte with the `true` value, plus some metadata.

What you can't do is to assign a `bool[]` to a variable of type `object[]`. This is because `bool[]` directly contains a single byte for each `bool`, while `object[]` contains a *reference* for each item.

Converting `bool[]` to `object[]` would be quite a big change: each `bool` would have to be boxed separately and a new array would have to be allocated for the references to these boxes. Because of that, the compiler doesn't allow you to do that directly.

What you can do to make this work is to create `object[]` from the start:

```
object[] dirBoolArray = { curLeft, curUp, curRight, curDown };
ExtendedArray dirBool = new ExtendedArray(dirBoolArray);
```

This will create an array of boxed `bool`s, which is exactly what you need.

Few more notes:

- Since you're using `Boolean`, maybe you're expecting that there is some difference between `bool` and `Boolean` (like in Java). In C# there is no difference between the two, `bool` is just an alias for `Boolean`.
- Using `object[]` is a code smell, which says you *might* be doing something wrong. It's certainly not “generic” in the way that word is usually understood in C#.

Comment: Your input was very useful svick. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Array co-variance only works if the members can be converted without changing their representation (plus some other restrictions).

This means that you can cast an array of a reference type to `object[]`, but you can't cast an array that contains value types to `object[]`. Converting from `bool` to `object` does not preserve the representation, and it's thus not possible to cast `bool[]` to `object[]`.

Comment: I doubt the OP knows what covariance is.